# C++ Doubly Linked List without OO concepts Insert into sorted list

Tags: c++, sorting

I've been encourage to use C++ without oo concepts. I've been working on the function called "InsertIntoSortedList" using doubly linked list. However, it allow me to insert the first node. For the second node and onwards, it will jump out from the function.[Here is the Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8EBU.png) . 
The code works fine on simple program, so i tried to using it on a more complicated program. i'll put the coding for both program below.

```
void InsertIntoSortedList(){

newnode = new carlist;
newnode->next = NULL;
newnode->back = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List is empty, Please insert Data: " << endl;
        cout << "ID: ";
        cin >> newnode->id;
        cout << "Description: ";
        cin >> newnode->description;
        cout << "Price: ";
        cin >> newnode->price;
        cout << "Stock: ";
        cin >> newnode->stock;
        head = tail = newnode;

    }
    else if (newnode->price < head->price) {

        InsertAtBeginning();
    }
    else {

        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (newnode->price > temp->price) {
                previous = temp;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp == NULL) {
            InsertAtEnd();
        }
        else {
            newnode->next = previous->next;
            previous->next->back = newnode;
            previous->next = newnode;
            newnode->back = previous;
        }
    }
```

it works fine on this program

```
void insertIntoSortedList(int eid) {
newnode = new employee;
newnode->employeeID = eid;
newnode->next = NULL;
newnode->back = NULL;
if (head == NULL) {
    head = tail = newnode;
}
else if (eid < head->employeeID) {

    insertatBeginning(eid);
}
else {
    temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        if (eid > temp->employeeID) {
            previous = temp;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (temp == NULL) {
        insertAtEnd(eid);
    }
    else {
        newnode->next = previous->next;
        previous->next->back = newnode;
        previous->next = newnode;
        newnode->back = previous;
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me what's the problem, and why it couldn't work ? i even try to draw out the doubly linked list, and i think it should be working just fine. This thing have been bugging me for a whole night. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: You really should use `nullptr`, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Some Problems:

1) The only place the function takes any data is if head is null. Take the input code out of the if statement, and debug from there.

2) To take more than one node, then you need some sort of loop. Best to place that loop, along with the input code you just removed above, into a main function:

```
int main() {

    newnode = new carlist;

    while (newnode != nullptr)
    {

        newnode->next = nullptr;
        newnode->back = nullptr;
        cout << " Please insert Data: " << endl;

        cout << "ID: ";
        cin >> newnode->id;
        cout << "Description: ";
        cin >> newnode->description;
        cout << "Price: ";
        cin >> newnode->price;
        cout << "Stock: ";
        cin >> newnode->stock;

        InsertIntoSortedList(newnode);

        cout << "To exit write \"exit\", or any other key to continue : ");
        string exitnow;
        cin >> exit;
        if (exitnow == "exit")
            newnode = nullptr;
        else
            newnode = new carlist;

    }



      return 0;
}
```

For the rest of the code that we are not seeing, best to use a debugger and try to understand what each control path is doing.

Comment: thanks I'd appreciate if you could accept the answer if it indeed helped you :)